# web based screen recording

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, browser, web

is there any way to have access to the client's system screen through the browser? i'm implementing an e-learning web application i need to implement screen-casting right through my application so i want to find a way of recording screen through the web browser exactly like Screenr service, i searched but found no suitable api, there was just a chrome extetntion and html2canvas that didn't exactly match my needs, they were able to capture browser tab! not the whole system screen. i know that Screenr is doing it through Java but i'm looking for a better and dependency free way of doing it, do you have any suggestion for me? thanks.

Comment: So, navigate to your web-based app, "login", download pure HTML/JS/CSS, and whammo, you're snipping screen captures of my entire screen? Yeah, if any browser allowed that natively, I wouldn't install it.

Comment: Nope. Sorry. If that were possible, then the act of browsing to a webpage (even without the security abyss that is Java) could give control of your computer over to some badly-dressed teenager in his mom's basement... And we wouldn't want that, would we?

Comment: there is some html5 apis that allow you to have access to the user's camera or mic there so no security issue with that because the browser asks the user for giving the permission to the app, i was wondering if there is any access api like that for my use, in development or in use!

Comment: FYI This is the relevant Chrome extension API method: [`chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab).

Comment: yes tab capturing can be done through html2canvas too but what i need is capturing the whole system screen, i'm using it for screencast recording service. much like Screenr

Comment: i guess the only way is to use Java RIAs Applet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok after some search and questions, i ended up with this answer:
to implement this, the best way is to use a java applet that get the user screen, of course it needs java installed and that's a disadvantage but this is the only way for now, i hope in the future some api for this is implemented in html just like filesystem api or the api that is used to access the user camera.